# Augmentation on the same sample

Tags: deep-learning, data-augmentation

Working on audio classification task where my inputs are raw audio samples and outputs are class labeles , and for this particular question, I want to augment only the Trainset split samples

Q: is it a good practice to augment the same audio sample more then one time ?

E.g., to apply to the same record `x`, first `aug1` , which yield `record_x_aug1_sample`, and later `aug2`, which yield `record_x_aug2_sample`.
Then the `Trainset` will hold both: `[record_x_aug1_sample,record_x_aug2_sample]` and a model will train on this `Trainset`

Q2: is it a good practice to also add the original record `x` to the `Trainset`?

Answer (score 1):

1. It is perfectly fine to augment the same audio more then one time. Moreover it is a good practice to reduce overfitting when your model each time takes slightly different versions of the same sample.
2. Yes it's fine. Also you can construct two datasets: 1. the original samples without augmentation 2. dataset with augmentations. Comparing the quality on those two dataset you can get a grasp of how strong your augmentations are. Also it can show the benefits of adding of augmentations to your training process.

Also you may consider augmenting your samples on-the-fly if you are using some iterative training process (like a neural network fitted with SGD). So the samples will be slightly different all the time. Pseudo-code:

```
for sample in dataset:
  augmented_sample = augment(sample)
  model.train(augmented_sample)
```

Another approach that may improve performance is first train on the augmented datasets. Then fine-tune the model on the clean original samples for few time.

Some libraries for audio augmentation:

https://github.com/iver56/audiomentations

https://github.com/asteroid-team/torch-audiomentations

Usage:

```py
from audiomentations import Compose, AddGaussianNoise, TimeStretch, PitchShift, Shift
import numpy as np

augment = Compose([
    AddGaussianNoise(min_amplitude=0.001, max_amplitude=0.015, p=0.5),
    TimeStretch(min_rate=0.8, max_rate=1.25, p=0.5),
    PitchShift(min_semitones=-4, max_semitones=4, p=0.5),
    Shift(min_fraction=-0.5, max_fraction=0.5, p=0.5),
])

# Generate 2 seconds of dummy audio for the sake of example
samples = np.random.uniform(low=-0.2, high=0.2, size=(32000,)).astype(np.float32)

# Augment/transform/perturb the audio data
augmented_samples = augment(samples=samples, sample_rate=16000)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and the answer. Can you explain the reason behind first train only on augmented dataset and then fine tune on the original samples ? Do you have maybe  a paper / article which used this method ?

Comment: When you are using augmentations the training data distribution *may* be shifted but in the end you need your model to work on the test dataset. So to match the distribution of the test dataset it *may* be beneficial to reduce effect of augmentation.

Comment: I'm validating and tuning the hyperparams only on non-augmented data , I thought you ment something else when you used "fine-tuning". Thanks !